# ClassCastException in OSGi embedded in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, osgi, activemq-classic, embedding, classcastexception

We have a framework that runs inside OSGi. One of our bundles uses ActiveMQ for JMS pub/sub based notifications. This bundle embeds the activemq jar inside the bundle (privately)

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 ....
 lib/activemq-all.jar,
 ....
```

All this works fine in all scenarios (except in one case - **embedding case**).

**Embedding Case:** Now we are dealing with scenarios where an application embeds our framework. That also worked fine until one of the embedding application started using activemq from their classpath. This embedding application is a tomcat based webapp and has activemq-all.jar in tomcat's lib.

We DO NOT export anything related to active-mq through our fragment bundles so there should be no visibility of activemq classes in tomcat classpath to our bundles but it seems to be happening.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportFactory cannot be cast to org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory 
at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.findTransportFactory(TransportFactory.java:201)   
... 24 more
```

We tried setting/resetting ContextClassLoader before/after creating ActiveMQ connections which seemed to have solved this issue but breaking a lot of other stuff (around Apache Tuscany SDO that we use) so it is NOT a viable option.

Question:
How come ActiveMQ classes are conflicting between app classpath and bundle classpath when they are completely disconnected? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand correctly, you start an embedded OSGi framework from a Tomcat webapp, and classes from the Tomcat classpath are now visible within the embedded OSGi environment.

I guess it depends on which classes you supply to the framework. For Felix (I don't know which OSGi implementation you're using) you can configure it using the [framework configuration properties](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-configuration-properties.html).

Maybe your problem is related to [this](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Why_does_Eclipse_find_javax.swing_but_not_Felix?) and your application sets: `org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=*`

Comment: The solution we found after many different trials was sort of bizarre and disproves the concept of class isolation in OSGi. The ActiveMQ classes were loading first in the app classpath. When the OSGi bundle was trying to load the same set of classes, it was loading alright but the interfaces were considered to be available from the classpath!

Comment: The way we solved the problem is by loading the ActiveMQ releated connectors (& thus classes) at startup of the Bundle (in activator) and letting the same classes to load in app classpath later. Thus the bundle got its own set of activemq classes. None of the activemq classes were ever exposed from fragments. This only reveals some of the loopholes of OSGi which still doesn't guaranty class isolation in some cases!